# how to Optimize response speed or performance of GeoWebcache from Openlayer Request

Tags: geoserver

I have TileLayer that contains a bunch of data on GeoServer2.13 and making the request from browser client using OpenLayers v4.1 API.
what all done is:

1.Openlayer Map with projection:

```js
var map: any = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'Map',
  projection: 'EPSG:900913',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: {
      collapsible: false
    }
  }),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

2.WMS Request as tiled True:

```js
layer: new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: _GESERVER_URL +'geo/wms',
        params: {
          'FORMAT': 'image/png',
          'VERSION': '1.1.1',
          'TILED': true,
          'LAYERS': 'geo':myTileLayer'
        },
        projection: 'EPSG:4326'
      })
    })
```

3.On GeoServer:

```
-Layer Data tab SRS:4326
  -Http Setting response header 3600
  -Seeding Executing task 1
  -ZoomLevel 15
  -GridSet:EPSG:900913 and EPSG:4326
  -Metatiling factors 4 by 4
  -Image Format image/jpeg and image/png
  -DiskQuata:3GB
  -TileDimensions:256 x 256
```

I also tried with image/png8 but still speed up is not at all working.
Any other configuration required to make GeoWebcache with more performance?

Comment: Are you using the proper [URL](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/using.html)?  http://example.com/geoserver/gwc/service/wms

Comment: Don't forget to seed the tiles (pre-render them), or to assess the speed impact the 2nd time your request a tile, not the 1st time as it has to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting the tiles in a different projection than your map is displayed in, which forces OpenLayers to reproject the tiles. This takes time and reduces quality.

Remove the line `projection: 'EPSG:4326'` from your WMS layer.

Also to be sure you are hitting your tile cache please use a tiled endpoint such as WMTS rather than hoping your tiles end up hitting the cache (unlikely since you don't specify an `origin` in your WMS). See the [OpenLayers WMTS example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts-layer-from-capabilities.html) for details.

```
var parser = new ol.format.WMTSCapabilities();
  var map;

  fetch('https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/WMTSCapabilities.xml').then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  }).then(function(text) {
    var result = parser.read(text);
    var options = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
      layer: 'layer-7328',
      matrixSet: 'EPSG:3857'
    });

    map = new ol.Map({
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM(),
          opacity: 0.7
        }),
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          opacity: 1,
          source: new ol.source.WMTS(/** @type {!olx.source.WMTSOptions} */ (options))
        })
      ],
      target: 'map',
      view: new ol.View({
        center: [19412406.33, -5050500.21],
        zoom: 5
      })
    });
  });
```